# How to trap SIGINT and SIGTERM (basically when Ctrl+C tapped) in CLI tool with Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, command-line-interface, swift-package-manager

I'm creating a CLI (executable product) for macOS using Swift Package Manager

My worker process some data and write the output to a file. I need to trap SIGINT, SIGTERM or any signal indicating that the command has been quit, so that I can inform my worker to clean things up.

Anyone has an idea how I can do it in a Swift Package target?

```
@main
enum CLI {
    static func main() async throws {
        let worker = Worker()

        await worker.process()
    }
}
```